# How to use new Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 4.x.x.x in asp.net app without have to compile the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

In my asp.net app, I am currently use old Oracle.DataAccess.dll(version 10.2.0.100).

Database was upgraded to 19c,  I want to replace with the new Oracle.DataAccess.dll ( version 4.x.x.x) , after binding redirect assembly in the web.config, I am getting error:

...'Oracle.DataAccess, version=10.2.0.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="somekey" which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess', Version=4.122.19.1 ....

how to fix this issue without having to recompile?  I don't want to compile the source with the new reference.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? I never heard about Oracle.DataAccess.dll version `10.2.0.100` - I know only version like `1.100.2.x` or `2.102.2.x` From where did you get the DLL?

Comment: What is the problem of recompile?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Nothing wrong with recompiled, but there are a tons of app to recompile.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit There is Oracle.DataAccess.dll  for Database 10g,  this is old, when open property of the file, it shows 10.2.0.100 in version.

Comment: Oh yes, I found it [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Installation Instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/windows-install10202.html). As far as I remember, the 1.x and 2.x/4.x versions are not compatible to each other, you need to compile your code anyway - perhaps you even have to make minor changes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Redirecting assembly versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

Create/modify an application config file (`application_name.exe.config` or `web.config`). Should be similar to this one:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
   </startup>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.2.0.100" newVersion="4.122.19.1" /> 
           <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I did try the suggestion, it still have the error saying that the current version 10.2.0.100 is higher version than 4.122.19.1